# Prevent TypeScript from compiling rest operators to for loops in compiled code

Tags: typescript

Given this TypeScript:

```js
get(...args) {
 return Reflect.get(...args);
}
```

Typescript will compile to:

```js
get: function get() {
  for (var _len2 = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len2), _key2 = 0; _key2 < _len2; _key2++) {
    args[_key2] = arguments[_key2];
  }
  return Reflect.get.apply(Reflect, args);
}
```

Over the course of a project, this ends up begin a significant byte inflation on an application that is ok with ES6 as a requirement. My tsconfig.json is has `target: "ES2016"`.

How can I let the compiler know I'm ok with using native rest statements?

Comment: What ts version do you run? Even old ts 3.3.3 compiles it fine https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ts=3.3.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXIpmAJ4DaAugJSIDeAUIi4hAvlIgG6IC8iALKYoACzQBbGGHRY8+GgG5EjAL5A

Comment: Well thats odd @zerkms I'm using 4.1.x. Specifically I'm using TSDX with this tsconfig.json: https://github.com/formium/tsdx/blob/master/templates/basic/tsconfig.json albeit mine has `target: 'ES2016'` as well.

Comment: FWIW — I filed an issue here: https://github.com/formium/tsdx/issues/963